# Deshabilitar una sección con $stateProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy realizando una web en la que existe un menú lateral, en el cuál se pueden activar u ocultar opciones.

Me gustaría saber si existe la manera de que si en el menú tengo lo siguiente:

```
> -seccion1
> -seccion2
> -seccion4
```

Las cuáles apuntan a 192.168.1.1/app/seccion1 ...

Me gustaría poder limitar la funcionalidad en el $stateProvider para que si acceden a la seccion3 (a la cuál se podría acceder desde url) pero no desde el menú, puesto que está oculta, no le permita acceder.

Actualmente tengo el siguiente codigo:

Vista

```
<li class="sidebar-list" ng-show="seccion1">
    <a ng-class="{ activo: isActive('/seccion1') }" href="#/seccion1">Sección 1</a>
</li>
```

routes

```
.state('seccion1', {
     url: '/seccion1',
     parent: 'menu',
     templateUrl: 'templates/seccion1.html',
     controller: 'Seccion1Ctrl',
     ncyBreadcrumb: {
         label: 'Sección 1'
     }
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estados, los state, podrían tener o no url, es opcional

ui-router te permite tener un state con "/", que no cambia la url, y que no se active por url, pero que lo manejes programáticamente mediante $state.go("seccion3");

Las otras secciones las pueden llamar directo pero section3,  nunca se activaría por url, de resto se comporta como los demás estados

AGREGADO:

```
.config(function($stateProvider) {  
    $stateProvider
    .state('stateSection1', {
        url: '/url1',
        views: {
            'viewPortSection1': {
                templateUrl: 'app/components/sections/views.section.1.html'
            }
        }
    }).state('stateSection2', {
        url: '/url2',
        views: {
            'viewPortSection2': {
                templateUrl: '/app/components/sections/views.section.2.html'
            }
        }
    }).state('stateSection3', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'viewPortSection3': {
                templateUrl: '/app/components/sections/views.section.3.html'
            }
        }
    }).state('stateSection4', {
        url: '/url4',
        views: {
            'viewPortSection4': {
                templateUrl: '/app/components/sections/views.section.4.html'
            }
        }
    }).state('stateSection5', {
        url: '/url5',
        views: {
            'viewPortSection5': {
                templateUrl: '/app/components/sections/views.section.5.html'
            }
        }
    }) 
})
```

En controler al momento de mostrar la seccion 3 programáticamente:

```
$state.go('stateSection3');
```

En la vista:

```
<div id="portalContainer" class="container-fluid" style="position: relative;top:-4px;">

        <div style="position: relative;height: 5px"></div>
        <div ui-view="viewPortSection1"></div>
        <div ui-view="viewPortSection2"></div>
        <div ui-view="viewPortSection3"></div>
        <div ui-view="viewPortSection4"></div>           
        <div ui-view="viewPortSection5"></div>                                          
</div>
```

Ya si después tienes que activar vistas simultáneamente, ui router también te dá los medios, puedes anidar, utilzar abstract, ojo que la url vacía "/" aveces presenta problemas en anidamientos demasiado complejos, pero bien es evitable si lo haces lo más simple que puedas en estructura

AGREGADO 2:

Adjunto esta información, que fué de utilidad:

https://www.genbetadev.com/javascript/ui-router-un-acercamiento-al-enrutamiento-flexible-en-angularjs

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-views

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir código a modo de ejemplo?

Comment: Si, tengo uno mano que estoy haciendo estos días.

El ui-router, entre otras, te habilita para realizar una Vista Compuesta, el patrón Compuesta, es lo de tener en una misma página, varios sectores independientes, similar al concepto de Portlets.

Edito arriba y actualizo

Comment: Perfectamente explicado! Gracias. Por lo tanto así por url no sería accesible, a no ser que haga click en el menú. Es correcto?

Comment: Así es, sólamente tu fuente puede activar el despliegue de la section sin url mediante el go, desde alguna sentencia de la lógica del controller.

Lo bueno de los states, es que fueron diseñados para ser Estados, conceptualmente son objetos más elaborados que simples Urls, y tienen más capacidades que los urls, de router normal.

Bueno, si fuera necesario, evalua si vale la pena además proteger accesos del lado servidor, ya que el js expone urls, deacuerdo a tu criterio

Comment: Hombre la verdad que ahora que lo comentas, me sería de gran interés el poder saber como se hace. He estado investigando, pero aun no he sacado nada en claro. ¿Me podrías facilitar algo de documentación, o guiarme por donde buscar?

Comment: Espero te sirva este, que tiene unas demos no muy trabajadas, pero explican muy bien todos estos conceptos:
https://www.genbetadev.com/javascript/ui-router-un-acercamiento-al-enrutamiento-flexible-en-angularjs 
...Si vas a requerir Composite View, formando una página con varias pequeñas vistas, o viewPorts, este te puede ayudar

Comment: Gracias de nuevo!! Me has sido de gran ayuda!